# Detect significant change in trend

Tags: time-series, forecasting, python, trend, structural-change

I am trying to find a good fit for my data, taking a multivariate analysis approach. That is I transform my data and do linear regression and pick the best one based on r squared.

The problem is sometimes my trend changes and therefore I get a poor fit for forecasting. 
My goal is to identify the point at which it changes and don't use any data before that point.

Since I want too detect the trend, I cannot transform my data first. So the data is non stationary.

I'm implementing this in Python so either pointers to an algorithm or and existing function are OK.
I'm new to this area, not quite sure how I should do this.

I tried detecting outliers in differences of slopes over different periods/slices but I'm hoping for something a bit more robust. It worked OK, if I manually adjusted the std for each series but I need something that works on its own ;)

Side note: I'm trying to do some type of data cleansing before I actually start the whole analysis of that makes sense.

Comment: What are you trying to fit to what?

Comment: I'm trying to fit a line/curve on a time series, but in order to get an accurate forecast I want to detect change in trend and omit unrepresentative points